# ! LaTeX Error: File `scrartcl.cls' not found. - TeXworks

Tags: miktex, texworks

Hye, I am new to Latex and using TeXworks software for document generations. It is working properly for simple article class but as soon as I added `\documentclass{scrartcl}`, it started giving me above error. I downloaded scrartcl.cls and added it in the same path where article.cls was but it is still not working. Both class files are currently in `..\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome, you can use the miktex package manager to install missing packages, in this case `koma-script`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please use the MiKTeX package manager to download and install package KOMA-Script.  Don't do it by your own!

Comment: I would recommend a full installation, rather than a basic. There will be much more packages you need to install (which can be done with the package manager or *on the fly*).

Comment: thanks everyone for your prompt replies. can someone provide me any link and where should I place those packages/files in folder hierarchy so compiler can read those?

Comment: Just let miktex install them, it will install them in the correct location.

Comment: @aneelasafdar If you're working with MikTeX is very easy to add/install packages. You can check the preferences and choose install missing packages on the fly or ask me first. In both cases MikTeX will search and install missing packages easily without you need to add them manually. You don't need to make a full installation as Johannes_B suggested. But if you want to avoid those problems, then probably you should follow his advice.